JPA Composite primary key and FK
I am trying to create a relationship between two tables. One of them has a user FK field ("Person") the other has a code field and a user field ("ROLE"). The PK is formed by code and name.
I have the classes defined as:
@Entity
@IdClass(RolPK.class)
public class Rol extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

    @NotEmpty    @Id    private String codigo = "";

    @ManyToOne    @JoinColumn(name = "usuario")
    @NotNull    private Persona persona;

    @Id    @NotEmpty    private String usuario; 

// +Getter Setters

@Entity
public class Persona extends AbstractEntity {

@NotEmpty    
@Id    
private String dni="";

@NotEmpty    
private String usuario =  "";

//+ Other non ID attibutes and getter setters

And the  IdClass
public class RolPK implements Serializable {

        protected String usuario;
        protected String codigo;

        public RolPK(String usuario, String codigo) {
            this.usuario = usuario;
            this.codigo = codigo;
        }

The error is given when compiling and currently says:
"Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Entity 'com.example.application.data.Rol' has '@Id' annotated properties 'id' which do not match properties of the specified '@IdClass'"
But it has exactly both fields and same type
I have tried to reproduce the solution offered in this question with no result.
JPA & Hibernate - Composite primary key with foreign key
